# How to install two different instances of click onces deployed application in same machine

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, clickonce

I have published a WPF based application through Click Once deployment process using visual studio 2013. When I installed, it created a folder in "\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\xxx". Now i want to install another instance of same application. For that I changed the name of "assemblyIdentity" of my application exe file that makes me enable to install another instance. After installed it, when I opened or saw application properties it founds that newly created application  reference the existing installed application. In "\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\xxx", it create another folder with my changed assemblyIdentity as prename.

I want that newly created instance will run stand alone, it shouldn't depend on existing instance. How can I attain it ?

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what i can suggest by reading you problem is the 2nd app is not changing it's reference path 
What you can try is to change the version of Assembly in assembly info and deploy the 2nd one with difference url location.